# Retrieve facebook profile info iOS6

Tags: facebook, ios6, social-framework

I have successfully prompted users to grant facebook permission, using the method below via SocialFramework, but can't seem to be able to retrieve and then display basic profile info (name, email, id, etc...) I imagine there are simple methods for this, but can't find them. Can anyone provide some help here? Thanks

```
-(IBAction)getInfo:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"FIRING");

ACAccountStore *_accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// We will pass this dictionary in the next method. It should contain your Facebook App ID key,
// permissions and (optionally) the ACFacebookAudienceKey
NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : @"284395038337404",
ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email"],
ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe};

// Request access to the Facebook account.
// The user will see an alert view when you perform this method.
[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                       options:options
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                        if (granted)
                                        {
                                            NSLog(@"GRANTED");
                                            // At this point we can assume that we have access to the Facebook account
                                            NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

                                            // Optionally save the account
                                            [_accountStore saveAccount:[accounts lastObject] withCompletionHandler:nil];
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            NSLog(@"Failed to grant access\n%@", error);
                                        }
                                    }];
```

}

Comment: Hi.. Have you got solution ? I am getting null response.

Comment: I actually haven't had a chance to test/implement the below solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

With the code you have posted you can access only to very basic info of the account you are getting, as screen name or description which is facebook in this case...

An example:

```
ACAccount *account = [accounts lastObject];
NSString *username = account.username;
```

In order to get more complete information as real name, email, etc. you need to make a SLRequest using the /me function of the graph facebook api.

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
NSString *serviceType = SLServiceTypeFacebook;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue setName:@"Perform request"];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:serviceType requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:nil];

    [request setAccount:account];

    NSLog(@"Token: %@", account.credential.oauthToken);

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        // Handle the response...
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            //Handle error
        }
        else {

            NSDictionary* jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"Error: Error serializating object");
                //Handle error
            }
            else {

                    NSDictionary *errorDictionary = [jsonResults valueForKey:@"error"];

                    if (errorDictionary) {

                        NSNumber *errorCode = [errorDictionary valueForKey:@"code"];

                        //If we get a 190 code error, renew credentials
                        if ([errorCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:190]]) {

                            NSLog(@"Renewing credenciales...");

                            [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){

                                if (error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                    //Handle error
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (renewResult == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed) {
                                        //Try it again
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        NSLog(@"Error renewing credenciales...");

                                        NSError *errorRenewengCredential = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Error reneweng facebook credentials" code:[errorCode intValue] userInfo:nil];

                                        if (renewResult == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed) {
                                            //Handle error
                                        }
                                        else if (renewResult == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected) {
                                            //Handle error
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                            NSLog(@"jsonResults: %@", jsonResults);
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}];
```

This code also checks the possibility of errors, some handling if the token has expired and running the network processes in background in order to not blocking the interface.

You will find all the info at the jsonResults dictionary, and you can access as follows:

```
NSString *name = [jsonResults objectForKey:@"first_name"];
NSString *lastName = [jsonResults objectForKey:@"last_name"];
NSString *email = [jsonResults objectForKey:@"email"];
```

Check facebook documentation for more information at: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Hope it helps!